# How to change the theme of the jqGrid?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jqgrid, themes

I'm looking for the way to change jqGrid theme for the current version.
I've started to use jqGrid in my ASP.Net MVC 2 application recently and download some demo solution/projects. I tried to change the theme of the grid by changing the theme ui javascript 
but it doesn't work for me. Looking at the [document](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs) doesn't help me much!

How are you changing the jqGrid's theme? 
I'm looking for:

1. List of css files that used to set up the ui of the grid.
2. Steps to change a theme to a new theme
3. Prefer to refer to the theme by online .css/.js url - so as to update the theme to latest version automatically

Answer (score 6):

jQuery user interface [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) provides 24 themes.

1. For changing `jqgrid` theme simply download [Redmond](http://download.jqueryui.com/download)(Scroll down and select theme click Download button) theme by selecting `Gallery` tab then click on **Calendar** image for `preview the theme` then click on `Download` button for downloading.
2. Extract the downloaded file `jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom` and paste it under `themes -> redmond` folder.

Below are the files to apply theme in jqgrid.

**Example:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/themes/redmond/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/themes/redmond/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-1.10.2.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/themes/redmond/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>
```

Change jqgrid theme use `jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css,` `jquery-1.10.2.js,` `jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js` files.

**Step: 1**

[image: themeroller]

**Step: 2**

[image: themes]

Answer (score 2):

Not for jQueryUI themes, but you can switch between jQueryUI and bootstrap variants. I'm using free jqGrid (a branch of trirand jqGrid), and you can tune the look-and-feel with two main options:

1. `guiStyles` (https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/dist/jquery.jqgrid.src.js#L600): `jQueryUI`, `bootstrap`, `bootstrapPrimary`, `bootstrap4`
2. `icons` : (https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/dist/jquery.jqgrid.src.js#L389): `jQueryUI`, `fontAwesome`, `glyph`