# how to change theme of grid using jqwidgets

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I am using jqgrid to display data. I am very new to this 
I have tried [How to change the theme of the jqGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731699/how-to-change-the-theme-of-the-jqgrid) but its not working for me.
Can anyone tell me how to change theme of grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the [jQWidgets](http://jqwidgets.com) Grid, you should do two things: include the CSS theme file and then set the widget's theme property to the theme's name. Example: [Styling and Appearance](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxgrid/jquery-grid-styling-and-appearance.htm?search=grid)

Answer (score 0):

jqGrid uses jQuery UI CSS for the grid by default. Thus you have to include some jQuery UI CSS. I'd recommend you to choose one from well-known CSS and use it directly from Internet. There are some common [CDNs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network), which provides servers in different locations of the world and which have long time interval for caching. As the result the CSS will be loaded quickly and the next loading will be made mostly from the local cache. As the results, the loading could be typically more quickly as loading form your private web site.

On [jQuery UI blog](http://blog.jqueryui.com/) you can find URLs to jQuery CDN, MaxCDN, Google Ajax Libraries API (CDN), Microsoft Ajax CDN and other.

The list of standard themes is relatively long: black-tie, blitzer, cupertino, dark-hive, dot-luv, eggplant, excite-bike, flick, hot-sneaks, humanity, le-frog, mint-choc, overcast, pepper-grinder, redmond, smoothness, south-street, start, sunny, swanky-purse, trontastic, ui-darkness, ui-lightness, and vader. You can choose someone and use it. For example

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"
       href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css">
```

In the same way [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) (it's the fork of jqGrid, which I develop) is accessible from two other CDNs too ([cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/free-jqgrid) and [jsDelivr](http://www.jsdelivr.com/#!free-jqgrid) CDN). See [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs) article for details.

As the result, the typical code, which uses free jqGrid can looks like described [here](http://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#the_first_grid_code):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Your page title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.12.1/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.12.1/js/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    //<![CDATA[
    $(function () {
        "use strict";
        $("#grid").jqGrid({
            colModel: [
                { name: "firstName" },
                { name: "lastName" }
            ],
            data: [
                { id: 10, firstName: "Angela", lastName: "Merkel" },
                { id: 20, firstName: "Vladimir", lastName: "Putin" },
                { id: 30, firstName: "David", lastName: "Cameron" },
                { id: 40, firstName: "Barack", lastName: "Obama" },
                { id: 50, firstName: "François", lastName: "Hollande" }
            ]
        });
    });
    //]]>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="grid"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/pqL7d004/1/) demo too.

In other words, you don't need to generate customized jQuery UI theme, but you should just use one from existing.